# Java applet loading log shows "Created Version ID"?

Tags: java, applet

I'm running an applet locally and after loading it once I see this:

```
...
security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.definition new value
com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1edb587
security: Blacklist revocation check is enabled
security: Trusted libraries list check is enabled
network: Created version ID: 1.0.0.0
network: Created version ID: 1.0.0.0
...
```

What does "network: Created version ID: 1.0.0.0" mean? What causes that to show up? The first time the applet loads it doesn't show that, but any subsequent time it does.

Comment: *What does "network: Created version ID: 1.0.0.0" mean?*  What does it matter?  People stress too much over the output from the console.